# MVC2: Need to route Urls containing # symbol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for a way to correctly route urls that contain the '#' symbol. For such urls i basically want to ignore the #.

For example I want Stores/Index/#/{storeName} to route to the Index action of the Store controller passing a single parameter  (storeName).

I have tried matching the literal '#' in the string but this is not working. (The action is called but the storeName parameter is not passed)

```
routes.MapRoute("RemoveHash", "Store/Index/#/{storeName}",
            new {controller = "Store", action = "Index", storeName = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

I have also tried having 2 parameters to the action (the first being the #), thinking that I could just ignore the # if it was passed (hacky i know)... but something goes wrong with the routing in this case and neither parameter is passed to the action.

I would like to avoid using a HttpHandler for this task, if I could handle this using the MVC routing system that would be ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Everything that follows the # (hash) sign in the URL is completely ignored when the browser sends a request to the server, so your ASP.NET MVC application could never get this value. Only client side javascript could read this value (using `window.location.hash`) and could pass it to the server using AJAX request and a normal URL (for example: `Store/Index/{storeName}`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will tell the javascript guys that what they want is impossible !

Comment: Not that I didn't believe you but i double checked this using fiddler and the request that leaves the browser only has the url before the #. So thanks once again

Comment: @nixon, FYI, HTTP request should sent the full URL including the `#` hash.